Google Play Console Dashboard Values into API
I've been working on an Android application that I have in Google Play Console, and it features various dashboards such as Monthly Active Users (MAU), Total Number of Downloads, Rating, and Active Installs. I want to integrate the data from these dashboards into PowerBI and my Database automatically.
While I understand that I can manually download the CSV files from the dashboard, I'm looking for a more streamlined solution using an API. However, I've encountered some hurdles in setting up the API access.
Despite having an Admin role, the option to access API through Settings Setup > API Access doesn't seem to be available in my Google Play Console. I've tried following tutorials, but they all lead to the same dead end.
If anyone has insights or suggestions on how to navigate this issue, I would greatly appreciate the assistance. Thank you!
I tried looking in forums, Youtube videos, Team Members but I really couldn't figure it out

I am looking for the same thing, but can not find the answer as well
